# select a value where a SUM()

Tags: mysql, sql

I have my Query here

```
SELECT o.id, SUM(t.num) AS num
FROM table_1 o
LEFT JOIN table_2 t ON t.id = o.id
WHERE num >= 2
GROUP BY o.id
ORDER BY num DESC
```

I'm supposed to `SELECT` the `o.id` only where the `SUM(t.num) >= 2`, But the results are totally wrong in the SQLFiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/754e15/2/0

All I want to do is to select records `WHERE num >= 2` and `ORDER BY num desc`, I don't even need to select the `SUM(t.num)`, so tried to remove it and replace each `num` with `SUM(t.num)` but got `Invalid use of group function`,

I aim to use `WHERE` instead of `HAVING`, It worked before with `HAVING`, But I want to use `WHERE` because it is faster.

Comment: Hint:  `HAVING`.

Comment: `WHERE` is processed *before* aggregation, `HAVING` *after*, thus different speed doesn't matter, because the result is different, too :-)

Comment: @dnoeth Out of the question, is the `JOIN`  results occurs after or before the aggregation? Is that why I can only use `HAVING`?

Comment: "It worked before with `HAVING`, But I want to use `WHERE` because it is faster." `WHERE` is faster because it has to do less work, but you get incorrect results. If you want correct results, switch back to `HAVING`.

Comment: A query is processed in following logical order: FROM/JOIN->WHERE->GROUP BY->HAVING->SELECT->ORDER BY

Comment: @dnoeth Oh, Didn't know that at all, So If I used a Subquery instead of join it would actually be worse than `having` in speed because the `select` occurs after `having`?

Comment: "_I aim to use `WHERE` instead of `HAVING`, It worked before with `HAVING`, But I want to use `WHERE` because it is faster._" This claim is ***complete and utter rubbish!*** The 2 clauses serve different purposes and so their relative performance is irrelevant. You might as say you want to use a kettle because it's faster than a fridge. You're taking the root of all evil to an absurd extreme. I suggest you rather focus on understanding the code ***first***, before focusing on performance. Performance is hard enough already; _impossible_ when you don't even understand the code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a sub-query like this:

```
SELECT * FROM 
(SELECT o.id, SUM(t.num) num FROM table_1 o
LEFT JOIN table_2 t
ON t.id = o.id
GROUP BY o.id) T 
WHERE num >= 2
```

Using the `WHERE` clause outside the sub-query